# Grunt task can't locate phantomjs driver

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am using a grunt task that calls the 'webdriver-manager' node module to start my selenium webdriver. Right now it is configured to launch chromedriver, and gives me this line whenever I launch the grunt task: 'start_webdriver':

[10:49:13] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/talain/development/gitClone/enterprise/Source/clients-root/clients-webui-root/clients-webui-interface/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/**chromedriver_2.29**

The phantomjs driver is located in the same directory as the chromedriver, but I don't know where the configuration is that would allow me to change it. Here is the full output of launching 'start_webdriver' grunt task:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/talain/development/gitClone/enterprise/Source/clients-root/clients-webui-root/clients-webui-interface/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt --gruntfile /Users/talain/development/gitClone/enterprise/Source/clients-root/clients-webui-root/clients-webui-interface/Gruntfile.js "testing:start webdriver"
Running "execute:start_webdriver" (execute) task
-> executing /Users/talain/development/gitClone/enterprise/Source/clients-root/clients-webui-root/clients-webui-interface/node_modules/webdriver-manager
[10:49:13] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/Users/talain/development/gitClone/enterprise/Source/clients-root/clients-webui-root/clients-webui-interface/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.29 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/Users/talain/development/gitClone/enterprise/Source/clients-root/clients-webui-root/clients-webui-interface/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.15.0 -jar /Users/talain/development/gitClone/enterprise/Source/clients-root/clients-webui-root/clients-webui-interface/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -port 4444
[10:49:13] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 8081
10:49:13.978 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32'
10:49:13.979 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-04-13 10:49:14.002:INFO::main: Logging initialized @277ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
10:49:14.062 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
10:49:14.062 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform MAC
10:49:14.062 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
10:49:14.062 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
10:49:14.063 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
10:49:14.063 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
2017-04-13 10:49:14.106:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.20.v20161216
2017-04-13 10:49:14.141:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@685cb137{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-04-13 10:49:14.174:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5bcab519{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-04-13 10:49:14.175:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @450ms
10:49:14.175 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

Answer (score 0):

`webdriver-manager start` does not have a way to launch with phantomjs. I would suggest launching it manually. You could launch it with:

```
java -Dphantomjs.binary.path=/path/to/phantomjs -jar /path/to/selenium-server-standalone.jar -port 4444
```

Why is there no phantomjs support in webdriver-manager? Protractor does not recommend or support phantomjs. See [browser support](http://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-support).